# Styling and formatting PHP multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

Good Evening

I have a PHP multidimensional array, which I need to format with the keys representing the table headers

for example, this multidimensional array below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [created_by] => xxxxxx@gmail.com
            [created_location] => -13.986192:33.766127:1047.799927:23.112000:23.112000:0.223117:13.597380:1586342395904.000000
            [created_device_id] => 862615040428205
            [modified_date] => 2020-04-08T10:39:18+00:00
            [modified_by] => rsageme@gmail.com
            [modified_location] => -13.986192:33.766127:1047.799927:23.112000:23.112000:0.223117:13.597380:1586342395904.000000
            [modified_device_id] => 862615040428205
            [server_modified_date] => 2020-04-08T10:39:23+00:00
            [javascript_state] => {"my_element_1":"2020-04-24T10:38:30.000Z","my_element_2":"rsageme@Gmail.com","my_element_3":{"latitude":-13.986229,"longitude":33.766117,"altitude":1046.299927,"speed":0,"accuracy":17.124001},"my_element_4":"(265)992 33 03 42","my_element_5":"28","my_element_6":1,"ZCMultiSelections_my_element_6":["area_25"],"ZCDisplayValue_my_element_6":"Area 25","ZCDisplayKey_my_element_6":"area_25"}
            [my_element_1] => 2020-04-24T10:38:30+00:00
                Longitude:33.766117,
                Altitude:1046.299927,
                Speed:0.000000,
                Accuracy:17.124001,
                Vertical Accuracy:0.000000,
                Provider:fused,
                Time:04/08/2020 12:38:52 GMT+02:00
            [my_element_4] => (265)992 33 03 42
            [my_element_5] => 28
            [my_element_6] => area_25
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [created_date] => 2020-04-02T13:29:30+00:00
            [created_by] => xxxxxx@gmail.com
            [created_location] => -13.986122:33.766106:1049.099976:30.607000:30.607000:2.054704:356.125214:1585834229760.000000
            [created_device_id] => 862615040428205
            [modified_date] => 2020-04-02T13:29:30+00:00
            [modified_by] => xxxxxx@gmail.com
            [modified_location] => -13.986122:33.766106:1049.099976:30.607000:30.607000:2.054704:356.125214:1585834229760.000000
            [modified_device_id] => 862615040428205
            [server_modified_date] => 2020-04-02T13:29:36+00:00
            [javascript_state] => {"my_element_1":"2020-04-17T15:28:43.000Z","my_element_3":{"latitude":-13.986202,"longitude":33.766111,"altitude":1049.099976,"speed":0.938858,"accuracy":21.461},"my_element_4":"(265)992 33 03 42 ext. 0","my_element_5":"20","my_element_6":1,"ZCMultiSelections_my_element_6":["area_25"],"ZCDisplayValue_my_element_6":"Area 25","ZCDisplayKey_my_element_6":"area_25"}
            [my_element_1] => 2020-04-17T15:28:43+00:00
            [my_element_2] => 
            [my_element_3] => Latitude:-13.986202,
                Longitude:33.766111,
                Altitude:1049.099976,
                Speed:0.938858,
                Accuracy:21.461000,
                Vertical Accuracy:0.000000,
                Provider:fused,
                Time:04/02/2020 15:28:50 GMT+02:00
            [my_element_4] => (265)992 33 03 42 ext. 0
            [my_element_5] => 20
            [my_element_6] => area_25
    )
)
```

In this case in PHP I want the keys like my_element_4 for example to be the table headers with all corresponding data below it.

Thank you in advance, I hope this was descriptive enough.

Comment: You have too many unclosed questions, IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I'm not sure exactly what format you want as output so I have just made it as an HTML table, but it should be easy to adjust. This also take into account if a row should miss a value.

Here you go:

````
// Transform data
$headers = [];
$rows = [];
$rowIdx = 0;
foreach ($data as $sample) {
    foreach ($sample as $key => $value) {
        if (!in_array($key, $headers)) {
            $headers[] = $key;
        }
        $rows[$rowIdx][$key] = $value;
    }
    $rowIdx++;
}

// Display data
$html = "<table><thead><tr>";
foreach ($headers as $header) {
    $html .= "<th>$header</th>";
}
$html .= "</tr></thead><tbody>";
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $html .= "<tr>";
    foreach ($headers as $header) {
        $html .= "<td>";
        $html .= $row[$header]?? '';
        $html .= "</td>";
    }
    $html .= "</tr>";
}
$html .= "</tr></tbody></table>";
echo $html;```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use two loops, the first one for the headers and the other one for the rows. Or just print the headers during the first iteration of a single loop.

```
foreach($data as $i=>$item) {
    $header='';
    $row='';
    foreach($item as $key=>$value) {
        if($i==0) $header.='<th>'.$key.'</th>';
        $row.='<td>'.$value.'</td>';
    }
    if($i==0) echo '<tr>'.$header.'</tr>';
    echo '<tr>'.$row.'</tr>';
}
```

Comment: If it did, please consider marking it as the solution.